# Group Series Data on same axis of Range Bar Chart in Reportviewer ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer2008

I'm trying to group series of date ranges on the same Y axis of a range bar chart in ASP.NET C# reportviewer RDLC. I am successful in doing so with a asp chart component on the page when using AddXY() but I failed in finding a way to do the same with the report chart component.
This is my chart setup in the report.

[image]

And that's how they appear. The top one is the chart component directly inserted in the page, the below one is the report.

[image]

I want the report chart to display the data in the same grouping concept as the chart at the top. 
The data table fields is as follows:

SeriesLabel, String   // Defines the data series group
rFrom, DateTime       // Starting date
rTo, DateTime         // Ending date
sSeq, int32           // This can be used to group the series as well

Please, advise.
Many Thanks,